# re-export textures

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I'm using a 3d scanner that generate a .OBJ file with tiangular mesh.
[image: Triangles mesh]

And automatically generate a .JPEG texture.
[image: 3d with texture]

But this texture comes like this:
[image]

Can I generate and export the texture with a proper UV layout using blender? 
Thanks <3

Comment: By "Normal" texture do you mean a normal map or a texture with a proper UV layout?

Comment: Proper Uv layout ^^
sorry about that
i was not clear...

Comment: The usual process would be to create a retopologized mesh based on the scan. This new mesh is UV unwrapped and then you bake the texture from the high poly to the retopologized mesh. The result is a clean model with a proper UV layout and only the necessary amount of vertices. Is there any particular part of the process you're having a problem with?

Comment: To retopologize the mesh, have any automatic way? Or do i have to make it?
And If i make the rotopo the texture will not be lost with the new mesh?

Comment: There are some automatic tools for remeshing, but they won't really help you get a proper topology that would allow you to properly place your UV seams. Therefore you would most likely have to do it manually.The retopologized mesh wouldn't have the texture, you would need to bake it from the original mesh to the retopo'ed mesh.

Comment: If you want to have an automatic solution use the Quad Remesher in *Object Data Properties > Remesh*. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZM9JZBmCxI